# How can i make a xml file from a multidimentional array in C#?

Tags: c#, xml, arrays, serialization

im making a xml file as a report from the data stored in my multidimentional array, just something like this:

```
string[,] twoDimentionArray = new string[2, 2] { {"Mike","Amy"}, {"Mary","Albert"} };
```

How can i make a xml file from this array in C#?

Thank you.

Comment: What do you want your XML to look like?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could also use [XDocument](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.linq.xdocument.aspx) if you didn't want to make a class to represent the data in order to use the serialiser (although personally I would recommend you do because any data structure more complicated than the one you have in your sample will rapidly become a maintenance problem!)

Note this code is deliberately "long-hand" for clarity, you can probably do it in a single nested statement.

```
string[,] twoDimentionArray = new string[2, 2] { {"Mike","Amy"}, {"Mary","Albert"} }; 
var doc = new XDocument();
var Couples = new XElement("Couples");
doc.Add(Couples);
for(int x=0;x<2;x++)
{
    var couple= new XElement("Couple");
    couple.Add(new XElement("Person1",twoDimentionArray[x,0]));
    couple.Add(new XElement("Person2",twoDimentionArray[x,1]));
    Couples.Add(couple);
}
Console.WriteLine(doc.ToString());
```

will produce

```
<Couples>
  <Couple>
    <Person1>Mike</Person1>
    <Person2>Amy</Person2>
  </Couple>
  <Couple>
    <Person1>Mary</Person1>
    <Person2>Albert</Person2>
  </Couple>
</Couples>
```

Comment: Thank you! It will help me in others samples, thank you so much.

Comment: no problem, but do check out m. edmonson's answer as the `XmlSerializer` will prove to be much more helpful to you in the long run!

Answer (score 1):

Use the [XmlSerializer Class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.serialization.xmlserializer.aspx):

> Serializes and deserializes objects into and from XML documents. The
>   XmlSerializer enables you to control how objects are encoded into XML.